# Compare two different table and find out mismatching time stamps

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to find out how many hours an employee was inside and outside office on his duty hours.

Below is the employee's duty hours

**CASE #1**

```
FromDateTime                ToDateTime
---------------------------------------------------
2017-12-11 07:30:00.000     2017-12-11 12:30:00.000
2017-12-11 15:30:00.000     2017-12-11 18:30:00.000
```

Below is the employee's attendance hours (inside office timings)

```
InTime                          OutTime
--------------------------------------------------------
2017-12-11 07:30:12.000         2017-12-11 07:34:29.000
2017-12-11 12:45:28.000         2017-12-11 13:04:15.000
2017-12-11 17:55:15.000         2017-12-11 18:04:28.000
```

When you compare above two tables, the expected inside and outside timings against duty hours should be below:

```
FromTime                    ToTime                      Remarks
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-12-11 07:30:12.000     2017-12-11 07:34:29.000     Inside Office
2017-12-11 07:34:29.000     2017-12-11 12:30:00.000     Outside Office
2017-12-11 12:45:28.000     2017-12-11 13:04:15.000     Inside Office
2017-12-11 15:30:00.000     2017-12-11 17:55:15.000     Outside Office
2017-12-11 17:55:15.000     2017-12-11 18:04:28.000     Inside Office
2017-12-11 18:04:28.000     2017-12-11 18:30:00.000     Outside Office
```

But I am getting result as:

```
FromTime                    ToTime                      Remarks
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-12-11 07:30:00.000     2017-12-11 07:30:12.000     Outside Office
2017-12-11 07:30:12.000     2017-12-11 07:34:29.000     Inside Office
2017-12-11 07:34:29.000     2017-12-11 12:45:28.000     Outside Office
2017-12-11 12:45:28.000     2017-12-11 13:04:15.000     Inside Office
2017-12-11 15:30:00.000     2017-12-11 17:55:15.000     Outside Office
2017-12-11 17:55:15.000     2017-12-11 18:04:28.000     Inside Office
2017-12-11 18:04:28.000     NULL                        Outside Office
```

I hope I cleared my question and below is the Query I wrote for this purpose:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeDutyHours TABLE  
(
    FromDateTime DATETIME,
    ToDateTime DATETIME
)

DECLARE @EmployeeAttendanceHours TABLE  
(
    InTime DATETIME,
    OutTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @EmployeeDutyHours
VALUES  ('2017-11-29 07:30:00.000', '2017-11-29 12:30:00.000'),
        ('2017-11-29 13:30:00.000', '2017-11-29 16:30:00.000')

INSERT INTO @EmployeeAttendanceHours 
VALUES  ('2017-11-29 07:27:24.000', '2017-11-29 09:44:33.000'),
        ('2017-11-29 11:57:37.000', '2017-11-29 12:05:39.000'),
        ('2017-11-29 15:12:31.000', '2017-11-29 17:24:32.000')

SELECT 
    FromTime = eah.InTime, 
    ToTime = eah.OutTime,
    Message = 'Inside Office'
FROM @EmployeeAttendanceHours eah

UNION

SELECT 
    FromTime = eah.OutTime,
    ToTime = eh.ToDateTime,
    Message = 'Outside Office'
FROM @EmployeeDutyHours eh,@EmployeeAttendanceHours eah 
WHERE eah.OutTime BETWEEN eh.FromDateTime AND eh.ToDateTime

UNION

SELECT 
    FromTime = eh.FromDateTime,
    ToTime = eah.InTime,
    Message = 'Outside Office'
FROM @EmployeeDutyHours eh, @EmployeeAttendanceHours eah
WHERE eah.InTime BETWEEN eh.FromDateTime AND eh.ToDateTime

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

What I should d to get the expected result?

**

> EDIT

**

[Below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47908010/9121898) answer is working for the above case and not working for the below case.

Below is the employee's duty hours

**CASE #2**

```
FromDateTime                ToDateTime
---------------------------------------------------
2017-11-29 07:30:00.000    2017-11-29 12:30:00.000
2017-11-29 13:30:00.000    2017-11-29 16:30:00.000
```

Below is the employee's attendance hours (inside office timings)

```
InTime                          OutTime
--------------------------------------------------------
2017-11-29 07:27:24.000         2017-11-29 09:44:33.000
2017-11-29 11:57:37.000         2017-11-29 12:05:39.000
2017-11-29 15:12:31.000         2017-11-29 17:24:32.000
```

The **expected** inside and outside timings against duty hours should be below:

```
FromTime                    ToTime                      Remarks
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-11-29 07:27:24.000     2017-11-29 09:44:33.000     Inside Office
2017-11-29 09:44:33.000     2017-11-29 11:57:37.000     Outside Office
2017-11-29 11:57:37.000     2017-11-29 12:05:39.000     Inside Office
2017-11-29 12:05:39.000     2017-11-29 12:30:00.000     Outside Office
2017-11-29 13:30:00.000     2017-11-29 15:12:31.000     Outside Office
2017-11-29 15:12:31.000     2017-11-29 17:24:32.000     Inside Office
```

But I am getting result after applying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47908010/9121898) answer:

```
FromTime                    ToTime                      Remarks
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-11-29 07:27:24.000     2017-11-29 09:44:33.000     Inside Office
2017-11-29 07:30:00.000     2017-11-29 11:57:37.000     Outside Office
2017-11-29 09:44:33.000     2017-11-29 12:30:00.000     Outside Office
2017-11-29 11:57:37.000     2017-11-29 12:05:39.000     Inside Office
2017-11-29 12:05:39.000     2017-11-29 12:30:00.000     Outside Office
2017-11-29 13:30:00.000     2017-11-29 15:12:31.000     Outside Office
2017-11-29 15:12:31.000     2017-11-29 17:24:32.000     Inside Office
```

Comment: Why FromTime 2017-12-11 07:34:29.000  ToTime 2017-12-11 12:30:00.000  is outside? It fits the employee hrs right?

Comment: Why is `(FromTime, ToTime)` = `(2017-12-11 12:45:28.000, 2017-12-11 13:04:15.000)` listed in the expected result. This period is outside the employee's duty hours, right?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos correct. but I thought to all of his timings when he is in inside office.

Comment: @Sobmac because the employee was NOT inside office that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the below query will work for you.

```
DECLARE @EmployeeDutyHours TABLE (
  FromDateTime datetime,
  ToDateTime datetime
)

DECLARE @EmployeeAttendanceHours TABLE (
  InTime datetime,
  OutTime datetime
)


--INSERT INTO @EmployeeDutyHours VALUES ('2017-12-11 07:30:00.000', '2017-12-11 12:30:00.000'),('2017-12-11 15:30:00.000', '2017-12-11 18:30:00.000')
--INSERT INTO @EmployeeAttendanceHours VALUES ('2017-12-11 07:30:12.000', '2017-12-11 07:34:29.000'), ('2017-12-11 12:45:28.000', '2017-12-11 13:04:15.000'), ('2017-12-11 17:55:15.000', '2017-12-11 18:04:28.000')

INSERT INTO @EmployeeDutyHours VALUES ('2017-11-29 07:30:00.000', '2017-11-29 12:30:00.000'), ('2017-11-29 13:30:00.000', '2017-11-29 16:30:00.000')
INSERT INTO @EmployeeAttendanceHours VALUES ('2017-11-29 07:27:24.000', '2017-11-29 09:44:33.000'), ('2017-11-29 11:57:37.000', '2017-11-29 12:05:39.000'), ('2017-11-29 15:12:31.000', '2017-11-29 17:24:32.000')


;WITH CTE
AS (SELECT
  *,
  LEAD(InTime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY InTime) AS NextIn,
  LEAD(OutTime, 1, '20491231') OVER (ORDER BY OutTime) AS NextOut,
  LAG(InTime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY InTime) AS PrevIn,
  LAG(OutTime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY OutTime) AS PrevOut
FROM @EmployeeAttendanceHours)


SELECT
  a.InTime,
  a.OutTime,
  'Inside Office' AS Remarks
FROM CTE a

UNION

SELECT
  a.OutTime,
  NextIn,
  'Outside Office'
FROM CTE a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @EmployeeDutyHours WHERE (a.InTime < ToDateTime AND a.OutTime > FromDateTime) AND a.NextIn BETWEEN FromDateTime AND ToDateTime) d

UNION

SELECT
  a.OutTime,
  d.ToDateTime,
  'Outside Office'
FROM CTE a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @EmployeeDutyHours WHERE a.OutTime BETWEEN FromDateTime AND ToDateTime AND a.OutTime < ToDateTime AND (a.NextOut > ToDateTime)) d

UNION

SELECT
  FromDateTime,
  a.InTime,
  'Outside Office'
FROM CTE a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @EmployeeDutyHours WHERE a.InTime BETWEEN FromDateTime AND ToDateTime AND a.InTime > FromDateTime AND a.PrevOut NOT BETWEEN FromDateTime AND ToDateTime AND a.PrevIn IS NOT NULL) d

ORDER BY InTime, OutTime
```

Comment case #1 and check your expected result.

As @combatc2 said, the employee was on case #1 was technically out for 12 seconds, if you want to include into result, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example - I think it solves what you're trying to accomplish; however, I don't think your expected results are entirely accurate - I think you're missing an "Outside office" of 2017-12-11 07:30:00.000 - 2017-12-11 07:30:12.000 for the first record as the employee was technically out for 12 seconds:

```
--DROP TABLE EmployeeDutyHours 
CREATE TABLE EmployeeDutyHours 
(
    EmployeeId BIGINT,
    ShiftFromTime DATETIME,
    ShiftToTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeDutyHours
    VALUES  (1, '2017-12-11 07:30:00.000', '2017-12-11 12:30:00.000'),
            (1, '2017-12-11 15:30:00.000', '2017-12-11 18:30:00.000')

--DROP TABLE EmployeeAttendanceHours 
CREATE TABLE EmployeeAttendanceHours 
(
    EmployeeId BIGINT,
    InTime DATETIME,
    OutTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeAttendanceHours 
    VALUES  (1, '2017-12-11 07:30:12.000', '2017-12-11 07:34:29.000'),
            (1, '2017-12-11 12:45:28.000', '2017-12-11 13:04:15.000'),
            (1, '2017-12-11 17:55:15.000', '2017-12-11 18:04:28.000')

SELECT 
    FromTime = eah.InTime, 
    ToTime = eah.OutTime,
    Message = 'Inside Office'
FROM EmployeeAttendanceHours eah

UNION

SELECT 
    FromTime = eah.OutTime,
    ToTime = eh.ShiftToTime,
    Message = 'Outside Office'
FROM dbo.EmployeeDutyHours eh
JOIN dbo.EmployeeAttendanceHours eah ON eah.EmployeeId = eh.EmployeeId
WHERE eah.OutTime BETWEEN eh.ShiftFromTime AND eh.ShiftToTime

UNION

SELECT 
    FromTime = eh.ShiftFromTime,
    ToTime = eah.InTime,
    Message = 'Outside Office'
FROM dbo.EmployeeDutyHours eh
JOIN dbo.EmployeeAttendanceHours eah ON eah.EmployeeId = eh.EmployeeId
WHERE eah.InTime BETWEEN eh.ShiftFromTime AND eh.ShiftToTime

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Your answer is working for case #1 but it failed on case #2. Please check and help!